# int object not callable

Tags: python, int, callable

Can't seem to find the issue:

```
def day_of_week(q,m,j,k):
    h=(q+((26(m+1))//10)+k+(k//4)+5j)%7
    return (h)

day=int(input("Enter day of month: "))
month=int(input ("Enter month: "))
year=str(input("Enter year: "))
century = year[0:-2:1]
c=int(century)
year=year[-2:]
y=int(year)
weekday=day_of_week(day,month,c,y)
print(weekday)
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 42, in <module>
    weekday=day_of_week(day,month,c,y)
  line 27, in day_of_week
    h=(q+((26(m+1))//10)+k+(k//4)+5j)%7
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read better this part of the function body `26(m+1)`

Comment: Thank you...Stupid mistake!